# Filter in select using Slick

Tags: sql, scala, slick

How can I do the following sql statement in Slick. The issue is that in the select statement there is filter and I don't know how to do that in Slick.

```
SELECT Sellers.ID,
       COALESCE(count(DISTINCT Produce.IMPORTERID) FILTER (WHERE Produce.CREATED > '2019-04-30 16:38:00'), 0::int) AS AFTERDATE,
       COALESCE(count(DISTINCT Produce.IMPORTERID) FILTER (WHERE Produce.NAME::text = 'Apple'::text AND Produce.CREATED > '2018-01-30 16:38:00'), 0::bigint) AS APPLES
FROM Sellers
JOIN Produce ON Produce.SellersID = Sellers.ID
WHERE Sellers.ID = 276
GROUP BY Sellers.ID;
```

Comment: Assuming this is a correct SQL, you could always use SQL interpolation - http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/sql.html

Comment: @Krzysztof Atłasik I know that, but the thing is that I want to make the SQL safe using Slick.

Comment: @namesy it appears [this question is an open issue](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/issues/455#issuecomment-521451962) and right now `slick-pg` is the only chance of having a FILTER clause in the aggregate expression

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._

case class Seller(id: Long)
case class Produce(name: String, sellerId: Long, importerId: Long, created: LocalDateTime)

class Sellers(tag: Tag) extends Table[Seller](tag, "Sellers") {
  def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def * = id <> (Seller.apply, Seller.unapply)
}

class Produces(tag: Tag) extends Table[Produce](tag, "Produce") {
  def name = column[String]("NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
  def sellerId = column[Long]("SellersID")
  def importerId = column[Long]("IMPORTERID")
  def created = column[LocalDateTime]("CREATED")
  def * = (name, sellerId, importerId, created) <> (Produce.tupled, Produce.unapply)
}

val sellers = TableQuery[Sellers]
val produces = TableQuery[Produces]

val dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val ldt2019 = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-04-30 16:38:00", dtf)
val ldt2018 = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-01-30 16:38:00", dtf)

sellers.join(produces).on(_.id === _.sellerId)
  .filter { case (s, p) => p.sellerId === 276L }
  .groupBy { case (s, p) => s.id }
  .map { case (sid, group) =>
  (
    sid,
    group
      .filter { case (s, p) => p.created > ldt2019 }
      .map { case (s, p) => p.importerId }
      .distinct.length,
    group
      .filter { case (s, p) => p.name === "Apple" && p.created > ldt2018 }
      .map { case (s, p) => p.importerId }
      .distinct.length
  )
}
```

`libraryDependencies += "com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg" % "0.18.0"`

Comment: How is `slick-pg` being used in your answer?

Comment: @ecoe `slick-pg` defines necessary implicit for `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Namely, implicit `slick.ast.TypedType[java.time.LocalDateTime]`.

Comment: My understanding is Slick doesn't support aggregate functions with a `FILTER` clause. Have you tested what query gets generated by this? I usually see run-time errors when running similar queries - as shown in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I really hope something like @Dymytro's answer can work, but from my testing it all comes down to limitations with the `GROUP BY`, and here are the issues you will run into:

1. Trying to use just `Slick` with a Postgres driver won't work because Slick doesn't support aggregate functions with a FILTER clause. Postgres is one of the few databases that supports FILTER! So you won't get far:

```scala
someQuery
    .groupBy { a => a.pivot  }
      .map{ case (pivot, query) =>
        (
          pivot,
          query
            .filter(_.condition === "stuff")
            .map(_.column).distinct.length
        )
      }
```

Although it compiles, you'll get some kind of runtime error like:

> [ERROR] slick.SlickTreeException: Cannot convert node to SQL Comprehension

2. Then, if you check out `slick-pg` you'll notice it has support for Postgres aggregate functions! Including the `FILTER` clause! But... there's an open issue for [aggregate functions with GROUP BY](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/issues/289) so this sort of attempt will fail too:

```scala
import com.github.tminglei.slickpg.agg.PgAggFuncSupport.GeneralAggFunctions._

...

someQuery
    .groupBy { a => a.pivot  }
    .map{ case (pivot, query) =>
        (
          pivot,
          query
              .map(a => count(a.column.distinct).filter(a.condition === "stuff"))
        )
      }
```

> No matching Shape found.
>   [error] Slick does not know how to map the given types.

So until those issues are resolved or someone posts a work around, luckily *simple single column* [`FILTER` expressions can be equivalently implemented with the more primitive `CASE` statements](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter#conforming-alternatives). Though not as pretty, it will work!

```scala
val caseApproach = someQuery
    .groupBy { a => a.pivot  }
    .map{ case (pivot, query) =>
        (
          pivot,
          query
              .map{ a =>
                Case If a.condition === "stuff" Then a.column
              }.min //here's where you add the aggregate, e.g. "min"
        )
      }

println(caseApproach.result.statements.headOption)
```

> select pivot, min((case when ("condition" = 'stuff') then "column" end)) from table group by pivot;